# How to write formula for bracketed function

Tags: functions

I am a Java programmer with little theoretical math experience.  I've written a plugin for a program, part of which runs a "bracketed" formula (I don't know what else to call it).  I have been asked to release the formula to an audience that may understand it better in math than in Java code.  So I need to know how to write this formula in math notations.
Here's how the formula works.  Suppose I have a certain number of Objects, and I want to derive a number of "Points" from them.  I call the following rules "brackets".

- For the first three objects, I want to count 1 point each.
- For the next 10 objects, I want to count .5 points each.
- For the next 30 objects, I want to count .1 points each.

So the results will be like this:

- 1 Object yields 1 Point.  (1 x 1)
- 3 Objects yield 3 Points.  (3 x 1)
- 4 Objects yield 3.5 Points.  (3 x 1  +  1 x .5)
- 5 Objects yield 4 Points.  (3 x 1  +  2 x .5)
- 13 Objects yield 8 Points  (3 x 1  +  10 x .5)
- 16 Objects yield 8.3 Points  (3 x 1  +  10 x .5 + 3 x .1)
- 43+ Objects yield 11 Points  (3 x 1 + 10 x .5 + 30 x .1)

This is an example of how the brackets are set.  The actual input in the program is customizable, and you can have more or less than three brackets.
How would I write this concept as a math equation or formula?

Comment: I guess your intended function is "piecewise linear" ... Do you want it written in cases, with absolute values, with maximum, what? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_function

Comment: @GEdgar I'm not sure I understood the question in your comment (I'm not really a math guy).  But thanks for the article, I found it helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rather direct translation: 
Let
$$r_i = \begin{cases}
1, &i\le 3 \\
\tfrac 1 2, & 4\le i\le 13 \\
\tfrac 1 {10}, & 14 \le i \le 43 \\
0, & 44\le i.
\end{cases}$$
Let
$$p_n = \sum_{i=1}^n r_i.$$

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I was looking for.  I vaguely remember using the big Sigma when expressing a function, but haven't touched it since high school.  I understand it now that I see it, and now I can express the code I've written in math.  Thank you!